# How do I retrieve a UID from a ICS file being accepted in an Outlook add in?

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin, mapi

Thanks for looking.

I am developing an Outlook Add-in and have a need to access the UID value embedded in a .ics file when the user accepts it:

[image]

If I view the raw data in the .ICS file, I can see that the UID is there:

[image]

I would like to know what event fires (that I can attach to) when a user accepts the meeting and, once I have the outlook object that is being accepted, how do I retrieve the UID from it?

## UPDATE:

Thanks to Dmitry Streblechenko's help I now understand that the Global Appointment Id is just an encoded version of the UID. His tool [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/home.htm)was very useful in seeing this. That said, I am still stuck on the last part which is to convert the Global Appointment ID to the UID in C#. Google leads me to this example to convert the `EntryId` property, but I can't locate the proper schema or hex code to get the Global Appointment ID property and decoded value. Any suggestions on how to modify the code below for the Global Appointment ID would be appreciated:

```
var oPA = appt.PropertyAccessor;

//Get EntryId Value
var entryIDProperty = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0FFF0102";
var entryId= oPA.BinaryToString(oPA.GetProperty(entryIDProperty));

//Now how to get the Global Appointment ID??
var globalApptProperty = http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x????????";
var globalId= oPA.BinaryToString(oPA.GetProperty(globalApptProperty ));
```

Thanks in advance.

## A SOLUTION

I realize that this may not be the best way to accomplish the goal, but it works so I am posting in case it helps anyone else:

```
var item = Item as Outlook.MeetingItem;
var appt = item.GetAssociatedAppointment(false);              
var oPA = appt.PropertyAccessor;
                
//This parses the Global Appointment ID to a byte array. We need to retrieve    the "UID" from it (if available).
byte[] bytes = (byte[]) oPA.StringToBinary(appt.GlobalAppointmentID);

//According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee157690(v=exchg.80).aspx we don't need first 40 bytes            
if (bytes.Length>=40)
{                    
   byte[] bytesThatContainData = new byte[bytes.Length - 40];
   Array.Copy(bytes, 40, bytesThatContainData, 0, bytesThatContainData.Length);

   //In some cases, there won't be a UID.
   var test = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytesThatContainData, 0, bytesThatContainData.Length);

   if (test.StartsWith("vCal-Uid"))
   {
      //remove vCal-Uid from start string and special symbols
      test = test.Replace("vCal-Uid", string.Empty);
      test = test.Replace("\u0001", string.Empty);
      test = test.Replace("\0", string.Empty);

      //Here is the result
      var uid = test;
    }else{
      // Bad format!!!
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract it from the AppointmentItem.GlobalAppointmentID property. Its format is documented at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee157690(v=exchg.80).aspx. If Data section starts with "vCal-Uid", the UID follows.

Comment: Thank you, but when I access the GlobalAppointmentId property (placing a breakpoint that is hit when user accepts meeting request) it is actually a different, much longer string. This was the original cause of my question actually, we are trying to sync meetings created online and meetings created in outlook via a common ID.

Comment: For example, the UID in the original invite is "augkaa383mj7v641rdikluit70@google.com" but the Global Appointment ID in the Outlook object is "040000008200E00074C5B7101A82E0080000000000000000000000000000000000000000320000007643616C2D556964010000006175676B61613338336D6A37763634317264696B6C756974373040676F6F676C652E636F6D00". Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, I as I mentioned before, the UID iss embedded inside that binary property. You would need to parse it. Take a look at the data with OutlookSpy - click IMessage button, select the GlobalObjectId property, click the "..." button next t the Value property.

Comment: Ok, I see, thank you! I have installed OutlookSpy and will try that now.

Comment: It's there, thanks! Now to figure it out how to grab it in C#. . .

Comment: Don't forget to test your parser with an appointment produced in Outlook - GlobalAppointmentId  will not have the native UID.

Comment: Thanks. I believe I am close here but struggling with the last bit. I have updated the question above with the code example and where I am stuck. I would be very grateful for any help.

Comment: Why are you parsing the entry id? You need the global appointment id property.

Comment: Yes, that was just an example. I don't know how to get the GAID.

Comment: OutlookSpy will give you the DASL name of that property in the DASL edit both.

Comment: Or you can just read the AppointmentItem.GlobalAppointmentId property.

Comment: And you need to use PropertyAccessor.StringToBinary to convert from a hex string to an array.

Comment: Thanks once again. I am still stumbling a bit but I want to spend some more time ensuring that I am not just making a silly mistake before asking another question.

Comment: Dmitry, thanks again for your help. I have gotten closer. If I turn the Global Appointment ID hex string into an array of bytes, I can then get a string that contains the UID by using Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes). The only remaining problem is that the UID is tucked into the resulting unicode and I don't know how to consistently isolate it. Any ideas? Thanks so much for your help thus far.

Comment: Here is the unicode I am getting: "\u0004\0\0\0�\0�\0tŷ\u0010\u001a��\b\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\02\0\0\0vCal-Uid\u0001\0\0\0bec7ig9javo9j8rdkg3i8p59oc@google.com\0"

Comment: Why are you using a Unicode string?  PropertyAccessor.StringToBinary will give you a byte array. You can then parse that array.